# Set DB to single-user mode, now I cannot open it in SMSS

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssms

In order to allow me to rename a database I set it to single-user mode. The rename worked fine but now trying to open the DB or even view its properties gives me connection errors. I've tried restarting SMSS but to no avail. All I wanted to do was rename it now I'm stuck. SMSS is generally acting very flaky.

What has gone wrong and how do I fix it? I'm running on Windows.

Comment: Make sure you have closed Object Explorer (and any other SSMS query windows you have open).

Comment: Is the database still in single user mode?

Comment: I couldn't get it out of single-user mode as I couldn't connect. I ended up deleting and recreating (luckily it's a new DB or this wouldn't be an option). Even then this was problematic but I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. restart sql server
2. open SMSS and login to sql server
3. on a new query run `ALTER DATABASE dbname SET MULTI_USER;` to set your db to back to Multi-user